# Android IAB v5: Querying product details is not supported

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am upgrading my app from IAB v1 to IAB v5.

I can successfully connect the Billing Client.

But if I then try to query product details, I get the warning from BillingClient:

**Querying product details is not supported.**

The query code is copied from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#java):

```
        QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
                QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setProductList(
                                List.of(
                                        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                .setProductId("premium")
                                                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                                .build()))
                        .build();

        billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                queryProductDetailsParams,
                new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                    public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                                                         List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                        // check billingResult
                        // process returned productDetailsList
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got details for " + productDetailsList.size() + " products." );
                    }
                }
        );
```

The `onProductDetailsResponseListener()` method is called, but the product details list is empty.

The `premium` product ID is a valid one, which was successfully purchased many times using the IAB v1 library.

Why do I get this warning message? Why is querying details not supported?

My gradle file pulls in IAB v5:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
}
```

### UPDATE 1

If I check feature support via the API using:

```
billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.PRODUCT_DETAILS);
```

I also get back `Response Code: FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED, Debug Message: Client does not support ProductDetails.`

The phone I test with has API 19 of the OS.

### UPDATE 2

It is worse than I thought! Without a product details result, I am unable to launch a purchase flow! At least with IAB v1, you could purchase without getting SKU details first.

### UPDATE 3

Whether product details feature is supported, seems to depend on the device.

With an API30 device, I get the feature support status:

```
PRODUCT_DETAILS support: Response Code: OK, Debug Message:
```

The IAB guide does not mention it, but it looks to me that IAB v5 is incompatible with an API19 device.

Comment: Same problem on my Nvidia shield, API30

Comment: I am facing the same problem when testing in Emulator, installed with Google Play. Previously, it works fine with Billing library 3.

Comment: Seeing the same problem on a Nexus 10 running Android 5.1.1 / API 22. Works fine with Billing Library 3 but not the latest.

Comment: Just had a report from a device (Galaxy A12, Android 11) running the latest versions of both Google Play Services (version code: `224814037`) and Google Play Store (version name: `33.5.17-21 [0] [PR] 493922335`) where the billing response code for `billingClient.isFeatureSupported(BillingClient.FeatureType.PRODUCT_DETAILS)` was `FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same thing but was able to get it to work on both of my two older devices (Nexus 9, Android 7.1.1 / API 25, and Nexus 10 running Android 5.1.1 / API 22) by updating the Google Play store on the device. I did this by:

- open the Play Store
- go to Settings inside the Play Store (by tapping my icon at the top right and choosing Settings from the menu)
- tap About
- Under Play Store version, I tapped "Update Play Store" and followed the prompts

It took a few tries of waiting for a download that I didn't see, and restarting the Play Store, but eventually tapping "Update Play Store" reported that it was up to date (version was 32.9.14-21). The Android 5.1.1 device had to download quite a few other updates before it worked so I had to be patient. I'm not sure which updates were critical so I just let it download all the built in stuff - doing just the store wasn't enough.

Neither device had been turned on or connected to the internet in quite a while (a couple of years), so I doubt customers are going to hit this.

After making sure both devices were done with updating, I re-ran the debug version of my app on the device and it was able to fetch prices per usual.

Comment: See my comment on the main question. Even with the latest version of Google Play Services and Google Play Store, this error can happen.

Comment: @Mark super frustrating for sure. I haven't had any reports from customers after releasing this update, but it's a small customer base.